# Android - Sending data from backgorund app to foreground app

Tags: android

I have two android apps (A and B), when app B is in background and app A is visible in foreground, I have to get data continuously from app B to app A which is in foregorund, How can i do this.?

Comment: i am not a pro but may be this will work , save data in "content provider" from background app and access it on foreground app

Answer (score 0):

Android provides IPC mechanism that is called bound service.
App B should work as service, provides data, and App A should work as client.
Make sure that app B has a service and the service can access shared data in order to provide the shared data.
You can [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) how to make bound service and how to communicate between service and client.

1. [Using a Messenger](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger)
2. [Using AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use custom broadcast receivers. This link will help you

[broadcast receivers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm)